# Example tabs.refresh() in JQuery 1.10 not working for me

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have an application that used the 'old' version of the JQuery tabs widget to dynamically add and remove tabs, i.e. it used `tabs.add()` and `tabs.remove()`.  I have spent two days trying to get the 'new' way using `tabs.refresh()` as stated on the JQuery upgrade guide to work and nothing is working but there are no javascript errors on the Chromium console.

This web page contains what I guess is the official JQuery example code:
http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-add-and-remove-methods-and-events-use-refresh-method

This is mycode that is doing nothing.  It is a cut and paste from the upgrade guide:

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs-nav" ></div>
<script>
    function addTab(fileName, url){
        $( "<li><a href='#" + url +"'>" + fileName + "</a></li>" ).appendTo( "#tabs .ui-tabs-nav" );
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs().tabs( "refresh" );
}
```

This function gets called as usual but there is no change to the ui.
Any ideas?

this is the entire application.  It shows a file picker then loops over the resulting list of file names creating a tab for each.  On the back end a server provides the content for each tab via the url that is passed to the tab.
    
    
     
    jQuery UI Tabs - refresh() replaces add,remove

```
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="master buttons">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="file" id="selectedFiles" style="display: none;" multiple onchange="buildFileTabs.call(this, event)" />
        <img src="select_files_button_image.png" alt="Image Not Found" onclick="showFilePicker();"  />
    </td>

</tr>
</table>

    <script>

        function addTab(fileName, url){
            alert("AddTab");
            $( "<li><a href='" + url+"'>" + fileName + "</a></li>" ).appendTo( "#tabs .ui-tabs-nav" );
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs().tabs( "refresh" );
        }

        function showFilePicker() {
            document.getElementById("selectedFiles").click();
        }       

        function buildFileTabs( page, event) {
            var theElement = document.getElementById('selectedFiles');

            for (var i = 0, numFiles = theElement.files.length; i < numFiles; i++) {
                var url="http://localhost:8080/FDS/FastDictionarySearchServlet?filename=" + theElement.files[i].name;
                  addTab (  theElement.files[i].name, url ) ;
            }
        }   

    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you paste all your codes

Comment: Prashant, I added the complete application to my post.  Have at it!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out how to do this.  As usual with me and JQuery, it is very simple when you finally get it right but a lot of trial and error is required to get there.

```
function addTab ( fileName ) {
    var url="http://localhost:8080/FDS/FastDictionarySearchServlet?filename=" + fileName ;
    var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    var ul = tabs.find( "ul" );
    $( "<li><a href='" + url + "'>" + fileName + "</a></li>" ).appendTo( ul );
    tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
}

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```